# Определяемся со стилем программирования!

Tags: visual-c++, c++, css

Если мы работаем с Visual C++, есть необходимость объявлять переменные, работать с библиотеками C, WinAPI, и т.д. Возникает вопрос как лучше и правильней объявлять типы переменных, например можно unsigned short, а можно WORD, или unsigned long, а можно DWORD, и т.д. Не хочется этой путаницы, как выработать правильный подход!?
И ещё, к примеру:

```
  DWORD WINAPI DdeQueryString( 
__in       DWORD idInst, 
__in       HSZ hsz, 
__out_opt  LPTSTR psz, 
__in       DWORD cchMax, 
__in       int iCodePage 
);
```

Как узнать расшифровку аббревиатур - LPTSTR (и им подобные), STR-string, PT-pointer, здесь понятно, а L-? Где можно получить информацию доступным языком?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте лучше WinAPI стиль кода. То есть вместо unsigned shor пишите WORD и так далее. Источник - гугл поиск по msdn.com. Там вам и C# + .NET и C++ + WinAPI.

Если вы пишите приложение и в будущем хотите перенести его на Linux, то старайтесь в основном коде не пользоваться вообще никакими платформозависимыми функциями, а только обверткой вокруг них. В этом случае, потом вы просто напишите другую обвертку с тем же интерфейсом под Linux и вуаля.

Если такая переносимость не планируется - можете смело использовать WinAPI и его псевдонимы.

Comment: Сейчас начнется холивар.

Comment: Мнения разделились!? :)

Comment: Да ладно вам. Если человек спрашивает какой стиль кода использовать, не думаю что у него в планах гигантское приложение работающее даже в пылесосе.

Comment: Приложение исключительно под винду, просто как то не красиво получается в одном месте unsigned short в другом WORD, пытаюсь определиться раз и на всегда! :)

Comment: Я думаю, что вот так вот определится и больше не использовать другой стиль не получится. Пишите одним стилем, а вот каким - выбирайте в зависимости от задачи.

Comment: Где дело касается WinAPI, пишите псевдонимы, в других местах - стандартные имена. 

Вообще, по сравнению с системными вызовами Unix WinAPI - что-то жуткое.

Comment: Полностью согласен, сиськи Unix'а более нативные на гляз для Си.

Comment: Где-то читал версию, что венгерскую нотацию (указание типа переменной в имени, типо lpsz) придумали для ассемблера, где само понятие типа не применимо. Да и ворды-дворды оттуда же пошли.

Answer (score 4):

LPSTR и проч. это одна из версий т.н. [Hungarian Naming Convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation), которая согласно одной из легенд была придумана разработчиками Windows. Венгерской она была названа из-за того что она труднопроизносима (венгерский как известно один из самых трудных языков в мире) и в честь одного из разработчиков венгра по национальности.

В данном контексте LPSTR означает Long Pointer to String - длинный указатель на строку. В те стародавние времена, когда память компов была сегментирована были т.н. длинные и короткие указатели. Короткие это указатели в пределах сегмента, а длинные в пределах всей памяти. Сейчас это архаизм, но LPSTR выжил. Заглавные буквы указывают что это тип.

Answer (score 2):

Подобные псевдонимы введены авторами WinAPI для лучшей переносимости, поскольку в разных версиях некоторые API работают с разными типами данных. Для переносимости и применяются псевдонимы.

А самый главный источник - MSDN.

Comment: Ну так в моём коде пользоваться псевдонимами или стандартным объявлением? Стиль то надо сразу вырабатывать!?

Comment: Если хотите переносимости между \*nix и Windows, **не пользуйтесь** DWORD, LPSTR ... и прочими из этого ряда, пишите где можно используя posix функции (родные WinAPI только в крайнем случае).

Answer (score 2):

Я объявляю свои типы. Например, так:

```
typedef unsigned short ushort;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned long ulong;
```

Сам я использую только их. Никогда ещё не было проблем с совместимостью WinAPI.

LPTSTR определён как `char*`, когда Юникод отключён, и `wchar_t*`, когда включён. LPCTSTR - то же самое, но с const. LPSTR и LPCSTR - то же самое, но всегда `char*`. LPWSTR и LPCWSTR - `wchar_t*`.

Считаю, что типы из WinAPI лучше не использовать. Всё, что написано большими буквами, обычно ассоциируется с макросами или константами. К тому же, эти типы (INT, LONG) не подсвечиваются редактором. Собственные ushort и uint хоть и тоже не подсвечиваются, но если ты решил использовать единственный стиль, то они подойдут по стилю к short, int и long.

Comment: В общем правильно, но не надо изобретать велосипед.

В \*nix (см sys/types.h но обычно "автоматом" подключается через  stdio.h и т.п.) приняты typedef-ы **u\_char, u\_short, u\_long** и т.п. На все размеры, для signed и unsigned.

IMHO это по **posix**.

Comment: Но это Unix, а в других ОС? Надо что-то общее.